# RecyclerView item not animating after calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

I'm currently developing an Android app using Material 3 components. I ran into a strange issue with animations.

I have a recyclerview that is populated based on data from a data class. When I try to load saved data and update the recyclerview by calling `notifyDataSetChanched()`, the data is loaded and displayed correctly.

For some reason, what I call the main cell, animations stop working. There is a switch and 3 edittexts in the main cell that stop animating. Also, the rest of the cells animate just fine.

[Here is a video showing the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ETA9A6kFJnn0XEisSuOg-QdheMB-F0KS/view?usp=sharing)

I've tried comparing my main cell XML to the other cells XML to see if there are any discrepancies, but it all looks ok to me.

If anyone knows what this could be a symptom of please let me know. Also if you'd like to see my code, please let me know. I didn't post any because it's pretty long.

Comment: You're not supposed to use `notifydatasetchanged` (I believe newer version of lib even has built in warnings for this), you should be providing diff with ListAdapter or manually with DiffUtils. If anything it's weird that any animations actually run when you use data set change.